# Prepositional usage of come

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I'm a non-native speaker.

I know for a fact that `come` is occasionally used as a preposition in informal contexts. See [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/come).

I.e.

> She would visit a new school come July

Now I wonder if there are any restrictions to that usage.

Could I, for example, write something like:

> I was preparing pizza dough for the come evening

Comment: It is not idiomatic, used in that way. But you could say: *I was preparing pizza dough, which would be very useful come evening*. Your wording would require *...for the coming evening*.

Comment: Why do you call "come" there a preposition?

Comment: @TimRomano
because oxforddcitionaries.com does: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/come

Comment: **come** there is a subjunctive form of the verb, *pace* the editors of that dictionary.

Comment: "Come" is a preposition in your first example. But you've used it incorrectly in your second example since you can't use it as some kind of noun modifier.

Comment: @Sprottenwels I think you meant to say for your second sentence "I was preparing pizza dough for the coming evening."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *come* is a preposition in such phrases as *come July*, *come evening*, *come dinnertime*...

You can hear thus usage in the Jimmy Buffett song "Come Monday" ([YouTube video & lyrics](https://youtu.be/qnKKlf_FGwg)).

In felicitous uses, *come ________* can be paraphrased by

*by the time   _________ arrives*, *by the time it is _________*, or *when ________ gets here*.

All the example sentences in Oxford can be paraphrased by using the expressions above.

It makes no sense in your sentence

> *I was preparing pizza dough for the come evening.

just as no prepositional phrase would make sense there.

You could say *the coming evening*.

You could say something like

> I was preparing pizza dough so we could cook pizzas come evening.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your example "I was preparing pizza dough for the come evening" - you can't put an article in front of prepositions.  Only nouns.

The usual way *come* as a preposition is used is *{ somebody } will / would / ought / should / must { do something } { for someone } come { time }.  Particularly *will* is usually used with *come* like this.  The modal is needed.  Your second example lacks the model so it sounds weird.

The time used after *come* is usually "far off" at least in a sense.  To use this with a short time frame such as *evening* implies you have a lot to do before evening.

> I will have the pizza dough completed come evening.  (I'm implying I have many things to do before the pizza dough will be completed.)
>
> I will have the car fixed come next week.  (This sounds natural.)
>
> I would have had the pizza dough completed come that evening, but ... (How to construct if you want to talk about this entirely in the past.  You need to qualify which evening because this construct is typically referencing a future time.)